# How to set a Text value for a label control of HeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

*ASP.NET using C#; .net3.5*

I want to set some value for this label `lblSkill1` Control. I'm unable to access `Skill1` in Eval function.

I'm unable to set some Text value in the place of `'<%# Eval("Skill1") %>'` for `lblSkill1` Control.

**HTML markup**:

```
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblSkill1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill1") %>'  />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
```

How can i set a value '**java**' in the place of `Skill1` as i said above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ItemDataBound Event you can find the control and set the value in your code behind file, I've presumed your using a Repeater.

```
protected void MyControl_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            var label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblSkill1");

            if (label != null)
                label.Text = "Text you want to set";
        }
    }
```

For a GridView.

```
protected void MyControl_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            var label = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSkill1");

            if (label != null)
                label.Text = "Text you want to set";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using Repeater control. I'm using GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The Header is meant for whole repeater whereas the item template is meant for each row.
You cannot use the EVAL Function in the header template as eval function is for current data item.

Comment: Not clear with your answer. I'm not using Repeater control. I'm using GridView

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use data-binding expression within header template because there is no current binding context available. For item-template, every item within data source will act as a data item and hence binding expression can work but not so for header template.

Say you have 5 rows in your data-source - what you expect `Eval("Skill1")` resolve to - against which item/row, you expect it to resolve against? If you just want to set the text dynamically by using code behind logic then use `<%=` or use `ItemDataBound` event. For example,

```
...
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <span><%= GetLabelText() %></span>         
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

where `GetLableText` will be a protected or public method in code behind class that will supply the needed value.

Note that I have use relevant html mark-up instead of server control because `<%=` will not work within server control property. On the other hand, if you choose to use data bound event then you have to user server control and find it using `FindControl` call.

Comment: I'm not using Repeater control. I'm using GridView.